# How to parse all variables in R?

Tags: r

in python to parse all the variables that have a name ending for example with "_df"
I would use something similar to what I found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/viewing-all-defined-variables-in-python/). How to do a similar thing in R?
Namely, I have several variables ending with _df and I have to do some actions to these.
Thanks

Comment: take a look at `ends_with` from dplyr or use `grep(".*_df$", your_files_names)` to locate files. This a general answer since your question is to broad. Provide a minimal example and we can help you better.

Comment: Sounds like you want `mget(ls(pattern = "_df$"))` It would be better to keep such related values in a list in the first place in R rather than separate variables in the global environment.